# Expression of type 'TelemetryClient' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'TelemetryClient' - Azure Queue Trigger

Tags: c#, .net, azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I recently added Storage queue to my existing application. It has nothing new comparing to other queue triggers I have already been running. Except the volume of messages it may get. We tested many times in Dev and it was working fine. We then deployed it to Prod with better resources, tried running and It was working as expected.

Then later an hour or so, we got system wide error,

`Expression of type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient' cannot be used for constructor parameter of type 'Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryClient' (Parameter 'arguments[0]')`

All of our other HTTP / Queue trigger had same error. Here is call stack,

```
System.ArgumentException:
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateOneArgument (System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Dynamic.Utils.ExpressionUtils.ValidateArgumentTypes (System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.New (System.Linq.Expressions, Version=4.2.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)
   at DryIoc.ReflectionFactory.CreateServiceExpression (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7306)
   at DryIoc.ReflectionFactory.CreateExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 7093)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetExpressionOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6544)
   at DryIoc.Factory.GetDelegateOrDefault (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 6624)
   at DryIoc.Container.ResolveAndCacheDefaultFactoryDelegate (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 209)
   at DryIoc.Container.DryIoc.IResolver.Resolve (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\DryIoc\Container.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 194)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.DependencyInjection.ScopedServiceProvider.GetService (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nullMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: D:\a\1\s\src\WebJobs.Script.WebHost\DependencyInjection\ScopedServiceProvider.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null: 25)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService (Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions, Version=3.1.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60)
   at lambda_method (Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: 37)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.DefaultJobActivator.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\DefaultJobActivator.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: 32)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1+<>c__DisplayClass1_1.<.ctor>b__0 (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxx: 20)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ActivatorInstanceFactory`1.Create (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxxxMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\ActivatorInstanceFactory.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: 26)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.CreateInstance (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxxMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionInvoker.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: 44)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+ParameterHelper.Initialize (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx5Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: 846)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor+<TryExecuteAsyncCore>d__16.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Executors\FunctionExecutor.csMicrosoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.16.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=xxxx: 116)
```

The Queue Trigger, which caused this problem, is a Twilio utility which updates calls as per requirements and can be triggered heavily. Like few tens per second.

So my question is what happened suddenly that it was generating this error for all azure functions? Was it a system crash? Was it the volume of requests it is getting? Do our resources fall short? Or our TelemetryClient has too many request in few seconds? Anything which can throw some light on this issue would be really helpful.